# RStudio: Possible bug on auto completion, requires testing

Tags: r, rstudio

Crashes RStudio on auto completion of column names on data frame objects on the right side of %in% (possible other circumstances).

```
# Code is not supposed to make much sense, just a minimal example to simulate crash
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10**7, 0, 5), y = rnorm(10**7, 0, 5))
df <- df[df$x %in% df$] ### TAB after second "$" to crash RStudio
```

I have posted this very same code example on RStudio support website. But it would probably be helpful to get a better sample of people that can reproduce the bug. If this bug is not exclusive to my machine, that is.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

RStudio Version 0.99.467
```

Update:

As suggested - I tried the very same operation on `0.98.1103`. What's interesting - it didn't freeze RStudio on completion on second `df$"TAB"` and returned the list of colnames as expected. However, now it didn't return completion options for the first `df$"TAB"` at all. Although without freezing the whole thing, that's less harmful in general.

Comment: Updated the question with version.

Comment: I encountered problem with completion with version `0.99.xxxx`. I downgraded to `0.98.1103`. Your example doesn't crash my RStudio.

Comment: 16GBs of RAM. And no execution is required on second line of code, just completion of column names. There are only 2 objects from perspective of colnames. Will try to do the same on 0.98.xxxx, thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Tried with RStudio version `0.99.484` and RStudio is hanging. I downgrade to `0.98.1103`.

Comment: You've reported this to the RStudio forum, which is what you should do. I don't see how this is a useful Stackoverflow question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it reports an IDE bug and SO is not the place for bug reports about software with their own support forum or bug tracker.

Comment: Primarily it was posted to determine whether it was a unique bug to my system and can be reproduced. In fact it was very harmful to me, given that I work with a lot of comparisons through data sets with long names. And also, I got a solution - install `RStudio 0.98.1103`. This can be a useful info to someone else too.

Comment: For the record, I have the same issue. RStudio 1.3 crashes when autocompleting  arguments of a user-defined function. downgrading to 1.2...